# Largest smallest value in sudoku like puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019001/math-puzzle-sudoku-like), a sudoku like math puzzle is proposed.

The grid must be filled while respecting a unique constraint : the sum of all $3\times3$ sub-squares must equal $2019$.

It is not that difficult to complete the grid, and there are many different solutions. I have noticed empirically that in every solution, the smallest value (among all cells) is at most $4$.

**Question** : is there an algebraic reason for this ?

The grid is in the picture below.

[image]

**Note** : the statement is easy to prove with a linear solver. Solving the following problem shows that the largest smallest possible value is indeed $4$.
$$
\max  \left\{  \min{ \{x_{ij}\} } \right\}
$$
subject to
$$
\sum_{k=i}^{i+2}\sum_{\ell=j}^{j+2} x_{k\ell} = 2019 \quad \forall i,j = 1,...,5
$$
where $x_{ij}$ is the value in cell $(i,j)$.

Comment: Just to be clear; your observation is that there is always a number less than $5$?

Comment: @Servaes : Yes exactly.

Comment: The number in middle cell of the bottom row is $4$. So the smallest value of any solution has to be at most $4$.

Comment: Also just to be clear; all entries must be positive integers?

Comment: @achillehui : aaaaa yes....of course. Thanks :) But how do you know another cell does not take value $3$ for example ?

Comment: @PeterTaylor : yes, indeed. This proves that the smallest value  is smaller than $4$. But it could be less, couldn't it ?

Comment: @Servaes : nothing in the initial post imposes positive integers.

Comment: @PeterTaylor : I agree that fleablood's answer proves that one cell is $4$. But does this prove that the largest smallest value is $4$ ? Perhaps the structure could be such that another cell must be $3$, in this case the smallest value would be at most 3, and not 4.

Comment: Start from @PeterTaylor 's solution, if one modify first row to
$$\begin{matrix}10 & 246-k & 250+k & 8 & 246-k & 250+k & 11\end{matrix}$$
for integer $k$, one can create solution with number as small as we like.
For example, $k = 243$ gives us a $3$ in the $2^{nd}$ and $5^{th}$ cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fleablood's answer to the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3019122/5676) fills in some more cells. Labelling the remaining ones with variables we get $$\begin{matrix}10 & a_{12} & a_{13} & 8 & a_{15} & a_{16} & 11 \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} & a_{26} & a_{27} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} & a_{36} & a_{37} \\
7 & a_{42} & a_{43} & 5 & a_{45} & a_{46} & 8 \\
a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55} & a_{56} & a_{57} \\
a_{61} & a_{62} & a_{63} & a_{64} & a_{65} & a_{66} & a_{67} \\
6 & a_{72} & a_{73} & 4 & a_{75} & a_{76} & 7\end{matrix}$$
Then the constraints on the 3x3 subsquares give 25 0-1 linear equations, each involving 8 unknowns, and there are 40 unknowns in total so the system is very underdetermined. Write them all out as a matrix, perform row reduction, and some rows drop out as linear combinations of others, leaving 21 rows in row-reduced echelon form, many of which are the original constraints. The simpler equations relate pairs: e.g. $a_{21} + a_{31} + 2 = a_{24} + a_{34}$. But none of the remaining unknowns is determined, and there's nothing stopping them all from being approximately $\frac{2000}{8} = 250$. For example, working by hand with one particular rref filling in 250s where not otherwise constrained I get a solution

$$\begin{matrix}10 & 246 & 250 & 8 & 246 & 250 & 11 \\
251 & 262 & 250 & 253 & 262 & 250 & 250 \\
250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 \\
7 & 249 & 250 & 5 & 249 & 250 & 8 \\
251 & 262 & 250 & 253 & 262 & 250 & 250 \\
250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 & 250 \\
6 & 250 & 250 & 4 & 250 & 250 & 7\end{matrix}$$